# Wms works on openlayers but not on leaflet

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, qgis

I have a wms published on qgiscloud.

On openLayers it works:

```
map.removeLayer(layers2);
console.log('wms');
var layers2 = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: 'http://wms.qgiscloud.com/marcorios7/cloudqgisTramos/',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'lonlattramos', 'TILED': true}           
})
        });            
        map.addLayer(layers2);
```

But, on leaflet it does not work:

```
var wmsLayer21 = 
L.tileLayer.wms('http://wms.qgiscloud.com/marcorios7/cloudqgisTramos/',
    {
        layers: 't1:lonlattramos',
        maxZoom: 24,
        //info_format: false,
        zIndex:1,
        opacity: 0.5
    }   
);
layersControl.addOverlay(wmsLayer21, 'GIS');
wmsLayer21.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

Not sure why you use `'t1:lonlattramos'` value for `layers` in your 2nd example whereas you used `'lonlattramos'` in your 1st one.

Once the 2nd example is corrected, it seems to work fine:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([14.5, -87], 6);

var wmsLayer21 =
  L.tileLayer.wms('http://wms.qgiscloud.com/marcorios7/cloudqgisTramos/', {
    layers: 'lonlattramos', //'t1:lonlattramos',
    maxZoom: 24,
    //info_format: false,
    zIndex: 1,
    opacity: 0.5
  });
wmsLayer21.addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```